# How can I center this iframe object in a top bar with Bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to vertically center a [GitHub button](https://github.com/mdo/github-buttons/) within a [fixed top-bar in Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-fixed-top/), but it keeps aligning along the top.

I tried using `vertical-align: middle`, but that had no effect.

```
.github-button {
    background: red; /* to visualize size */
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

[image]

If I set the inner element's height and padding, I get the desired placement, but that seems fragile and "hacky".

```
.github-button > iframe {
    padding-left: 13px;    
    padding-top: 10px;     
    height: 45px;          
}
```

[image]

Here's the fiddle (widen your browser page or the panel size to switch from mobile mode to desktop mode):
http://jsfiddle.net/aE9PS/2/

Any ideas on how to implement this cleanly? I'm open to suggestions of 3rd party libraries. Thanks

Comment: Nothing hacky about using padding if needed. You've got a simple solution. Use it and move on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `.github-button` has a `height: 100px;`, replace it with `30px` (to match the height of the iFrame)
2. The top bar has a height of `50px`, so add `margin-top: 10px;`

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ianclark001/aE9PS/5/)

Answer (score 1):

### check [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aE9PS/6/)

#### CSS

```
.github-button {
    background: red;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding-left: 13px;    
    padding-top: 7px;     
    height: 45px;  
}
```